# Populating a numpy array with values from a list while keeping relations

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have a list where the columns are ID#, date, value. So just for this example, lets say it looks like this:

```
[('1', 13152, '131'), 
 ('1', 13168, '-9999'), 
 ('1', 13177, '345'), 
 ('2', 13152, '-9999'), 
 ('2', 13168, '212'), 
 ('2', 13177, '693'),
 ('3', 13152, '456'), 
 ('3', 13168, '-9999'), 
 ('3', 13177, '103')]
```

Each ID# has three dates with three different values. Date range is the same for each ID#. Now I want to reformat this list.

So, I have a numpy array created like this.

```
[[   -9999.    13152.    13168.    13177.]
 [       1.    -9999.    -9999.    -9999.]
 [       2.    -9999.    -9999.    -9999.]
 [       3.    -9999.    -9999.    -9999.]]
```

I want to populate the numpy array with the values in the list and make sure it's in the correct spot in the array. I need to be able to do this for a bunch of other lists too. How do I systematically take the first ID in the list search for that ID number in the array and make sure they match? If they match use the date to find the correct column in the array and the fill cell with the value in the list.

Comment: What's your desired final output?

Comment: The arrays will be exported to CSVs which I will be using in another analysis. Note: The examples I gave are simplified versions of the real lists and arrays I will be working with. Same three columns but I'd have thousands of ID#s and dates spanning years.

Comment: I suggest using pandas rather than numpy for this.

Comment: I haven't used pandas much. How would I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible solution I could think of:

```
import numpy as np

a = [('1', 13152, '131'),
 ('1', 13168, '-9999'),
 ('1', 13177, '345'),
 ('2', 13152, '-9999'),
 ('2', 13168, '212'),
 ('2', 13177, '693'),
 ('3', 13152, '456'),
 ('3', 13168, '-9999'),
 ('3', 13177, '103')]

b = -9999*np.ones(shape=(int(len(a)/3+1), 4), dtype=int)
b[0, 1] = 13152
b[0, 2] = 13168
b[0, 3] = 13177
for i, el in enumerate(a):
    if int(el[1]) == 13152:
        b[int(el[0]), 0] = int(el[0])
        b[int(el[0]), 1] = int(el[2])
    if int(el[1]) == 13168:
        b[int(el[0]), 2] = int(el[2])
    if int(el[1]) == 13177:
        b[int(el[0]), 3] = int(el[2])
```

Then **b** is equal to:

```
[[-9999 13152 13168 13177]
 [    1   131 -9999   345]
 [    2 -9999   212   693]
 [    3   456 -9999   103]]
```

I'm pretty sure that you can more efficient solution, but it should do the  job. Also, as someone already mentioned in the comments, using pandas may be a good alternative.

**EDIT:**

In case of many dates you can for example use sets to determine all unique IDs and dates, and a dictionary to store number of column corresponding to given date:

```
import numpy as np

a = [('1', 13152, '131'),
     ('1', 13168, '-9999'),
     ('1', 13177, '345'),
     ('2', 13152, '-15'),
     ('3', 13152, '456'),
     ('4', 43, '-17'),
     ('5', 131123477, '103')
     ]  # slightly modified example to have more dates and values and see if everything is still working ;)

dates = set([el[1] for el in a])  # stores list of all unique dates from your dataset
ids = set([el[0] for el in a])  # the same for IDs
b = -9999*np.ones(shape=(len(ids) + 1, len(dates) + 1), dtype=int)  # allocates memory for your array
dateCol = {}  # empty dictionary for storing number of column corresponding to given date
for i, el in enumerate(dates):
    dateCol[el] = i+1  # storing number of column
    b[0, dateCol[el]] = int(el)  # setting label in first row

for i, el in enumerate(a):
    id = int(el[0])  # casting id to int
    b[id, 0] = id  # inserting id into first column
    b[id, dateCol[el[1]]] = int(el[2])  # inserting value into the column corresponding to given date
```

Then **b** is equal to:

```
[[    -9999     13152     13177        43     13168 131123477]
 [        1       131       345     -9999     -9999     -9999]
 [        2       -15     -9999     -9999     -9999     -9999]
 [        3       456     -9999     -9999     -9999     -9999]
 [        4     -9999     -9999       -17     -9999     -9999]
 [        5     -9999     -9999     -9999     -9999       103]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply machnic. The problem with this solution is that it only works for the example I gave. In reality I have thousands of ID#s and many different dates to format. With this solution I'd have to write a line for each individual date in the for loop.

Comment: Check my edit - I added more general solution which should solve your issue.